# C# Adding variable to the path

Tags: c#, sql

I'm wondering is it possible to add parameter as path in C# code which contains different paths? These paths come from SQL table,
as path = "C:\y" I would like to add my parameter.

This is the code:

````
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            string path;
            path = "C:\\y";
            //string path = @"\\192.168.2.55\\xstation_logs\\REAL\\logs\\fra-XST5-REAL-N1\\2020\01";
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string newpath = "C:\\x";
            try
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < dirs.Length; j++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirs[j].Replace(path, newpath));
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            for (int j = 0; j < files.Length; j++)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Copy(files[j], files[j].Replace(path, newpath));
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }```
````

Comment: Yes. It can be parameterized and pulled from DB as well. In DB, you'll have the paths with single \ and not escaped.

Comment: Try following : string paths = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) for include expression in an interpolated string.

Example:

```
string source = "y";
string target = "x";

string path = $@"C:\{source}";
string newpath = $@"C:\{target}";
```

Hope this helps.